# How to mount a btrfs subvolume via fstab? Has the root subvolume to be already mounted elsewhere?

Tags: fstab, btrfs, crypttab

I'm trying to mount two btrfs subvolumes from a same (luks-encrypted) device via the entries in `fstab`. The `crypttab` entry must be correct, since the system asks for the password on boot. But then it hangs with a black screen. The entries are:

(**this example is correct, the only problem was the wrong UUID, which was of the encrypted partition, not the decrypted mapped device**. I'll leave the question in case anyone searches for a specific working example of `btrfs` and `fstab`).

```
UUID={same uuid for device under /dev/mapper} /home/me btrfs defaults,ssd,subvol=home-me-dir,noatime 0 3
UUID={same uuid for device under /dev/mapper} /tmp btrfs defaults,ssd,subvol=tmp-dir,noatime,nodatacow,nodatasum 0 4
```

I tried both `subvol=path` and `subvolid=id` options. I ran `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` as was mentioned in the fstab file.

I'm not sure whether my problem is with it or with `systemd` (I suspect the issue is with `fstab` and `btrfs` since IIRC I did this with `ext4` and everything worked OK). So could anyone answer this, please:

- How to specify a path for the subvolume in the options, i.e. the `subvol=path` option? There were no examples in the `man 5 btrfs`, only the statement, that the path is always relative to the root subvolume, so I tried `subvol=some-dir` and `subvol=/some-dir` to no avail;
- Does the root subvolume have to be mounted to use the `subvol=path` or `subvolid=id` options for its children subvolumes in `fstab`? When I use `subvol=some-dir` the decrypted device is not even mounted yet.

Thank you.

Comment: just let's forget about `fstab` and what happens in boot process for now, can you manually mount your subvolumes? if not please provide `btrfs subvolume list` and `btrfs subvolume show`.

Comment: @binarysta yes, I can. At least on a live system. I decrypted the device, and then `sudo mount -o subvolume=home-me /dev/mapper/crypt some-path` it works. It must be then something with systemd targets

Comment: ok `umount` it and run `mount -a`, this will try to mount all the entries in `fstab`, if any issue with `fstab` entries we can find.

Comment: @binarysta thank you, you solved it actually. Somehow in fstab I had UUID of the encrypted device /dev/sda1 instead of the mapped decrypted device